# Check when last check for Windows Updates was performed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-update

How can I check WHEN last check for windows updates was performed - in code (c#/.Net)?

Not WHICH updates are or are not installed, but WHEN last check was performed?

Best of all would be a complete history of when checks for windows updates had been performed, but I can certainly live with only knowing the last check.

Comment: What version of Windows (not sure if it matters, but may help)?

Comment: Pretty much universal/modern. I guess something like Win2003 server/Vista and forward - 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at this registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results`

It has 3 sub keys that each provide different information about the different events

- Detect
- Download
- Install

Each key has a `LastSuccessTime` value you can use.

Comment: I do not have a `Results` key in `AutoUpdate` on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm not sure if that information is correct, I checked on my system and I have updates installed after the value I found on the 'Install' subkey. I have Windows 7. So at least for me is not reliable.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows 7, 8, 10 you can use following code:

```
var auc = new AutomaticUpdatesClass();

DateTime? lastInstallationSuccessDateUtc = null;
if (auc.Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate is DateTime)
    lastInstallationSuccessDateUtc = new DateTime(((DateTime)auc.Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate).Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);

 DateTime? lastSearchSuccessDateUtc = null;
 if (auc.Results.LastSearchSuccessDate is DateTime)
     lastSearchSuccessDateUtc = new DateTime(((DateTime)auc.Results.LastSearchSuccessDate).Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

- Reference "C:\Windows\System32\wuapi.dll".
- Check whether EmbeddedInteropTypes on reference is set to False.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to use this method for remote machines as well?

Comment: How do I get AutomaticUpdatesClass() ?

Answer (score -7):

In Windows 7, go to Control Panel, System and Security, Windows Update.  There is an option to see a history of all the updates, which gives time and date of each.